# Homomorphic encryption based on XOR

Tags: encryption, symmetric, homomorphic-encryption

Consider the values $a$ and $b$ are encrypted as $c_1=(a \oplus D)$ and $c_2=(b \oplus D)$.

My question is: can we derive $b+a$ from any combination of $c_1$ and $c_2$?

Note:

1. I admit that the $D$ should have not been used for both $a$ and $b$. For now assume we can use it.
2. Basically I define the values ($a$ and $b$) in $Z_p$, accordingly the result in $Z_p$.

Comment: What do you mean by b+a? b XOR a?

Comment: a and b are two values (say message), we pick a random value D, then XOR (exclusive or) a and D we denote the result by C1 , we XOR b and D ,we denote the result C2. Now the question is whether given D , c1 and c2 can one compute a+b ?

Comment: Its still not really answerable. YES: If you have an XOR homomorphic cipher (like [Golderwasser-Micali](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldwasser-Micali_cryptosystem)), where the message space is $\{0,1\}$ (bits), then given c1 (as an encryption of a XOR d) and c2 (as an encryption of b XOR d), then the product of c1 and c2 modulo n gives a ciphertext to (a XOR d) XOR (b XOR d) = a XOR b (and a XOR b is addition in GF(2), so this can be seen as a+b). Clearly, a,b and d are bits. You need to be more precise in your definition of message space etc.

Comment: Basically I define the values (a and b) in Zp, accordingly the result in Zp

Comment: What does XOR in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ mean?

Comment: Going back to the question in the comment, I tried to clarify that the value a and b are defined in Zp, however the XOR is defined as normal, therefore the result (at least it seems to me that) would be defined in the same Zp.

Comment: So you are defining XOR in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ as bitwise XOR the two values together, then do a MOD p?

Comment: Yes,exactly....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the additional details in the comments, it seems like your question is: given $c_1=a\oplus d$ and $c_2=b\oplus d$, can we get $(a+b)\oplus d$. Where $a,b,d\in\mathbb{Z}_p$, $+$ is addition modulo $p$, and $\oplus$ is a bitwise XOR of the values, then taken modulo $p$.

Or put another way, is there an operation $\boxplus$, such that $(a\oplus d)\boxplus (b\oplus d)\equiv (a+b)\oplus d\bmod{p}$?

Hopefully I've understood the problem correctly.

The answer is no, except in the trivial case of $p=2$, or more generally (if $p$ is not necessarily a prime) when $p=2^q$ for some prime $q$. That is because in these two cases, in the finite field $\mathbb{Z}_p$, $\oplus$ and $+$ are traditionally the same operation (note that by $+$ I am not talking about integer addition modulo $p$, I am referring to addition in the finite field). Or put another way $+$ is defined as bitwise xor in these fields.

In the case where $p\neq 2$ and $p\neq 2^q$ for some prime $q$, the bitwise XOR destroys all algebraic structure necessary for there to be an operation $\boxplus$. Now, what you can do is use $+$ instead of $\oplus$. Then you have $(a+d) + (b+d) = (a+b) + (d+d)$ and to decrypt, subtract $(d+d)$. If doing this, you should use different $d$ values for each message. In other words $(a+d_1) + (b+d_2) = (a+b) + (d_1+d_2)$ and to decrypt, subtract $(d_1+d_2)$. The $d_i$ values must be randomly chosen.

**Full disclosure**: My answer is based on intuition. It might be hard to prove that $\boxplus$ does not exist, but it seems very unlikely that it does. Basically we need associativity between $\oplus$ and $\boxplus$ (i.e., $(a\oplus b)\boxplus c = a \oplus (b\boxplus c)$ and $\boxplus$ must be commutative ($a\boxplus b = b\boxplus a$). There are lots of candidates for commutativity, but I can't think of any for that type of associativity.

Comment: But for $p = 2^q$, we have $(a \oplus d) \oplus (b \oplus d) = (a \oplus b)  \neq (a \oplus b) \oplus d$ – or do you want to define $x \boxplus y := x \oplus y \oplus d$?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann re first comment, you mean $=(a\oplus b)\neq(a\oplus b)\oplus d$ right? I was more going along the question of the OP "can we derive b+a from any combination of c1 and c2". In this case, we can derive $a\oplus b$ from some combination of c1 and c2.

Comment: yes, typo (now fixed). Yes, but the "field of order $2^q$" doesn't have the same addition (or multiplication) as the ring $\mathbb Z/_{2^q \mathbb Z}$, so you shouldn't talk about "$\bmod 2^q$" here. (It is now clearer after your edit.)

Comment: Does not make sense, the answer got 4 points but the question that got -1 point !!! It means good answer for rubbish question !!

Comment: @user153465 If I had to guess, I'd guess the - votes came for the original question since it had a lot of holes. I gave it a +1 after your clarifying comments were added in.

Comment: @mikeazo Well, without any doubt, you have been very helpful. Hopefully next time my questions would be more precise. Since I'm new in this forum he could have left comment asking for question modification.